# CookieUseSlidingExpiration do not renew the cookie properly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm a little bit stuck here, any help would be greatly appreciated (first post on SO, sorry if I'm doing something wrong).

I managed to use the ASP.NET Core CookieAuthentication to create different cookie per route. If I call http://host/API/moduleName1/login it will create a authentication cookie with a path set to /API/moduleName1 that will be used to authenticate a user only for calls under this path. To do that, I plugged myself on the SigningIn event and hacked the cookie path.

My Configure() code:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "...",
            CookieName = "...",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            CookieHttpOnly = false,
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnSigningIn = CustomAuthenticator.SigningInAsync,
                OnSigningOut = CustomAuthenticator.SigningOutAsync,
            }
        });
```

And my customisation:

```
public static class CustomAuthenticator
{
    public static async Task SigningInAsync(CookieSigningInContext context)
    {
        string controller = context.HttpContext.GetRouteValue("controller").ToString();
        string moduleName = context.HttpContext.GetRouteValue("moduleName").ToString();
        context.CookieOptions.Path = context.HttpContext.Request.PathBase + "/" + controller + "/" + moduleName;
    }

    public static async Task SigningOutAsync(CookieSigningOutContext context)
    {
        string controller = context.HttpContext.GetRouteValue("controller").ToString();
        string moduleName = context.HttpContext.GetRouteValue("moduleName").ToString();
        context.CookieOptions.Path = context.HttpContext.Request.PathBase + "/" + controller + "/" + moduleName;
    }
}
```

It worked well for a while, but then, playing with the cookie ExpireSpan set to 1 minute I discovered something annoying.

When I log myself in, I get something very logical:a session cookie with a properly set cookie path: '/API/PLENG'

But after a while, if I remain active, because of the CookieUseSlidingExpiration set to true, the middleware decide to renew my cookie and here is what I get: A second cookie with a cookie path set to '/'. Instead of renewing my cookie properly, the middleware created a new one that is completely messing with my design.

[double cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05bYT.png)

So I get that it's kind of my fault for having hacked the system, but I can't live without this Sliding Expiration mechanism and I'm left with no idea right now.

Can someone tell me how I should have done that in the first place (instead of hacking the cookie path)? Or how I could fix the buggy Sliding Expiration = true behavior.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by making the authentication cookie per-path instead of application-wide?

Comment: I need people to log themselves on that portal for various 'module', and then to dislatch to request to the proper modules. For example, if I log myself through http://host/module1/login, then I'll be authenticated for all request http://host/module1/rqt1, http://host/module1/rqt2 ... same for another module2, module3 ... I need the very same portal to provide that login feature for several 'modules'.

Comment: Have you considered using a single site-wide login, with roles defined per module?  That way you wouldn't have to hack anything.  The [FormsAuthenticationTicket.UserData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.userdata.aspx) field is specifically designed for this purpose.  [Sample code here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289844(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Thing is I have a different set of users per module. So if I create a cookie that says I'm authenticated it needs to say I'm authenticated for that module ? It doesn't look like it would fit exactly my need would it? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JohnWu I'm not sure my previous comment was very clear, so let me explain a little bit more. If I log myself in for module1, I'll be logging myself as John Doe from module1 users set, but if I log myself on module 2, I want a different identify, belonging to the set of users of module2. So the role concept, with a single principal/identity wouldn't work well I believe. Unless I'm missing something. Thanks.